# What's the path for the Rust standard library location for CLion on Windows?

Tags: windows, rust, clion

I am getting started with Rust and I am using [the Rust plugin for Clion](https://intellij-rust.github.io/). When I create a new Rust project, I need to specify the location of the stdlib. For whatever reason, it's not auto populating with the correct path. When I click `Download via rustup` nothing happens.

What's the path for the Rust standard library?

[image]

Comment: Did you install rustup ?

Comment: I did but I reinstalled clion and the issue seemed to go away.

Comment: Yes, you need to install rustp before CLion installation.

Answer (score 2):

I use wsl with Windows and the path to the standard Rust libraries is this:

```
\\wsl$\kali-linux\home\myUserName\.rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu\lib\rustlib\src\rust
```

Only to get this I searched because right after installation it didn't work either.

I had to delete all my toolchains directory from wsl
with

```
rm -frv ~/.rustup/toolchains/* directory
```

and then install it again by doing

```
rustup update
```

and

```
rustup -v component add rust-src
```

otherwise I didn't have the standard Rust libraries in my installation and I got a

```
/lib/rustlib/src': No such file or directory
```

error

when testing

```
ls ~/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/src
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who are having challenges, this is the location on Windows (assuming stable/x64):

```sh
C:\Users\<user>\.rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\lib\rustlib\src\rust\src
```

Answer (score -1):

Put standard library path as "c:\Users\andrew\.cargo\registry".